# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_json_data()

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, laragon

[image]

Here's the error upon opening php file using Docker Desktop:

0.1.2
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_json_data() in C:\laragon\www\myproject\public\index.php:37 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\myproject\public\index.php(40): get_channels() #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\myproject\public\index.php on line 37

Local link is: localhost

I have the ff. extensions installed on VSCode:

PHP Debug
PHP Intelephense
PHP Extension Pack
PHP IntelliSense

Answer (score 1):

use `json_decode` instead of `get_json_data`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the edit in `settings.JSON` inside `VS Code` had this wrong path:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

I had to `delete` the project and `clone` it again and now it works fine. Path shows:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.19-Win32-vc15-x64/php.exe",
```

Thank you!